# Profiling u-Boot/Kernel boot sequence

Tags: c, profiling, linux-kernel

I am profiling the booting process of power PC board, what is the simplest way to profile the booting sequence ?

My first idea is to modify the u-boot/kernel code add printf/printk (using  realtime device as reference) and print them on the console. However just printing them on the console may affect the time.

Any thoughts?

Regards,
Robert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that printing may affect performance (I don't think so unless you are printing less then about 10kbytes/s) then store that data in memory and print it later.

Answer (score 5):

There is a wonderful utility called [bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) which will give you a graphical representation of the boot process and tell you when each task started and how long it took to complete.

Check it out.

[image]
<sub>(source: [bootchart.org](http://www.bootchart.org/images/bootchart.debian.mcrae.1.png))</sub>

Comment: bootchart is nice, but only profiles from init onwards, as I understand it. Doesn't help with profiling u-boot/kernel load

Answer (score 3):

Everyone knows the best way to profile an u-boot is with sonar.

Comment: I am not talking about u-boat but u-boot ;-)